# Find all values which fits conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in excel, which has some table headers, which I consider as attributes for each row. I would like to find all the rows, which match my search query.

An example:

Based on my table below, I would like to find all the rows, where the author are Hemmingway and the year is 1926 (I need to be able to use several conditions). The result should present all the rows (including all the data in that row) that fits the conditions.

Is this possible with a function in excel or can it be accomplished using vba with excel?

[image: Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use advanced filters (in the Data Tab near the filters in the bottom right corner of that section). The way they work is you have to write the headers of the columns to search and under those headers conditions that you would like to match.

For your case, you'd have to create something like this:

```
Author     Year
Hemmingway 1926
```

Then select the entire table, select advanced filters and in the `Criteria range` select what I just showed you.

Using advanced filters you can have multiple rows of selection criterias so you can search for a few different things. You can also use operators (like <1950 for the year).